# Environment variable not recognised in ant script

Tags: java, ant, junit, environment-variables

I have a simple Ant script and I would like to use the environment variable JUNIT_HOME to pass to the  tag. The environment variable appears to be valid when it is echoed:

```
<echo message = "JUNIT_HOME: ${env.JUNIT_HOME}" />
```

Produces the correct output:

*JUNIT_HOME: "C:\Program Files (x86)\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_4.8.2.v4_8_2_v20110321-1705"*

But when I use it in the following way, the build fails claiming that it cannot find junit.

```
<target name="compile" depends="checkJUnitHome, init" description="compile the source ">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpath="${env.JUNIT_HOME}\junit.jar">
        <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

If I replace the environment variable with the full path. It works correctly.

What am I missing?

Kind regards,

Mark Coleman

Comment: Does JUNIT_HOME variable contains really the path including quotes? That may be the problem.

Comment: Hey Robert, that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `<property environment="env"/>` before you can access the environment.

*Edit*

You could try to move the classpath variable as property to the inner classpath element. See this one:

```
<target name="compile" depends="checkJUnitHome, init" description="compile the source ">
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="project.classpath" />
            <path location="${env.JUNIT_HOME}\junit.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Maybe its overriden...

Comment: Thanks matcauthon but I already did that. As you can see at the beginning of the post, I can already echo the variable correctly.

Comment: Thanks for trying again, but I'm afraid that also doesn't work. (Also I think you're missing a closing </classpath> tag.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert pointed out, the environment variable had been saved with double quotes. Removing these fixed the problem.

Thanks.